# org.json.JSONObject vs Gson library JsonObject

Tags: android, json, gson, android-json

What are differences between this two classes?

If someone uses Gson library is it preferable to use **`com.google.json.JsonObject`** over **`org.json.JSONObject`**?

Could anybody list pros and cons of these 2 choices?

Answer (score 24):

Following are the main differences:

1) GSON can use the Object definition to directly create an object of the desired type. JSONObject needs to be parsed manually.

2) org.json is a simple, tree-style API. It's biggest weakness is that it requires you to load the entire JSON document into a string before you can parse it. For large JSON documents this may be inefficient.

3) By far the biggest weakness of the org.json implementation is JSONException. It's just not convenient to have to place a try/catch block around all of your JSON stuff.

4) Gson is the best API for JSON parsing on Android. It has a very small binary size (under 200 KiB), does fast databinding, and has a simple easy-to-use API.

5) GSON and Jackson are the most popular solutions for managing JSON data in the java world.

Comment: Under 200KiB is not small at all for a JSON parser. in that regard, org.json latest version as of today is 65KiB, quite a lot smaller.

Comment: Regarding #3, I have never used try/catch blocks when using org.json.  Is it possible your experience is out of date (or that the library has changed since you wrote this answer)?

Answer (score 15):

Many JSON implementations are available in the market and most of them are open source. Each one has specific advantages and disadvantages.

- Google GSON
- Jackson
- org.json  etc.

**Google GSON** [click](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) for official documents

- Provide simple toJson() and fromJson() methods to convert Java objects to JSON and vice-versa
- Allow pre-existing unmodifiable objects to be converted to and from JSON
- Extensive support of Java Generics
- Allow custom representations for objects
- Support arbitrarily complex objects (with deep inheritance hierarchies and extensive use of generic types)

**Jackson** [click](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs) for official documents

- Streaming API or incremental parsing/generation: reads and writes JSON content as discrete events
- Tree model: provides a mutable in-memory tree representation of a JSON document
- Data binding: converts JSON to and from POJO’s

Some comparison blogs click here [blogs1](http://blog.takipi.com/the-ultimate-json-library-json-simple-vs-gson-vs-jackson-vs-json/), [blog2](http://www.developer.com/lang/jscript/top-7-open-source-json-binding-providers-available-today.html)

I personally done a benchmark for serialization and deserialization using GSON vs Jackson vs Simple JSON

- Very small object: Google gson performs faster than Jackson and Simple JSON
- Large objects : Google gson performs faster than Jackson and Simple JSON

Comment: So, Google gson is a superior library in terms of performance for small and large objects?

Comment: Sorry, what is "Simple JSON"?

Comment: hey @GrabNewTech! looks like you made a typo in your benchmark conclusions here...
afaik GSON failed the competition for big files where jackson won

Answer (score 2):

I did experiment with 456 Kb json file on real Pixel 3 device Android 11.
I need to create a backup file from database. Model has 3 objects with one-to-many relationships: Note, Item, Alarm.

```
Note -> fields and List<Item>.
Item -> fields and List<Alarm>.
Alarm -> fields

Serialization result:
gson -> 75ms; org.json -> 63ms
gson -> 83ms; org.json -> 67ms
gson -> 73ms; org.json -> 62ms
```

As you can see the default android org.json is faster than GSON.
If you have a time to create a mapping for your model, I recommend using the default org.json.
If you want to create json faster than gson, but more easy than org.json try using moshi or maybe kotlinx-serialization.